# comparing code in Associative Arrays to hard coded values

Tags: php

I have a text file with the following values which would be used as a username and password

root=>user
roots=>password
blabla=>moonbeam
help=>me

Code for a function validateUser in a file validateUser.php

```
function validateUser($username, $password)
{
    $filename = 'userCreds.txt';
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    if($file==false)
    {
        echo"Error opening file";
        exit();
    }
    $i=0;
    static $Credentials = array();
    foreach (file($filename) as $line)
    {
        list($key,$value) = explode("=>",$line,2) + array(NULL,NULL);
        if($value !== NULL)
        {
            $Credentials[$key] = $value;
        }

    }
    print_r($Credentials);
    echo "<br>";
    //static $Credentials = array("root"=>"user","rtam"=>"password","q"=>"continuum");

    if(array_key_exists($username, $Credentials))
    {
        echo "$Credentials[$username] <br>"; 
        echo "$password <br>";
        if($Credentials[$username] == $password)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $Credentials[$username]," is not equal to ",$password,"<br>";
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Code for the main file:

```
<?php

include_once "validateUser.php";
$username = "root";
$password = "user";
if(validateUser($username,$password))
{
    echo "<h2>Welcome! <br></h2>";
}
else 
{
    echo "Try again <br>";
}

?>
```

The values for $username and password are hardcoded from the beginning for testing purposes.
The problem I have, is when I get to comparing the username and password from the text file and comparing the two, they don't match.

Even when I print out the two values i.e. $password and $Credentials[$username], I get equal values on screen but the if statement doesn't recognize it using if($Credentials[$username] == $password).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you verify that you don't have extra spaces/tabs in your text file ?

Comment: yes, they are no extra spaces or tabs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try to trim the values in your validateuser function - wouldn't be the first time a \n or \t or simple space caught me out.

```
if($value !== NULL)
    {
        $Credentials[trim($key)] = trim($value);
    }
```

If that's not the case then maybe you can use regex to strip our any non alphanumeric chars from username and password.

eg

```
$key = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $key);
$value = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $value);
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked but why does it work? Does the text file add a \n at the end automatically?

Comment: If you read the docs for "file" you can see that File returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the NEW LINE STILL ATTACHED. Hence when you use "LIST" the $value still has the new line "\n" in its value.  You could edit your "FILE" command to strip new lines by entering the following flag

foreach (file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line)

and you can then stop using the trim function